# Find and filter last column with values

Tags: excel, vba

I need a code that will find the last column with values and filter that column by multiple criteria. Here’s what I’ve come up with so far.

```
Dim LastCol As Integer
With ActiveSheet
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
End With
With ActiveSheet
    AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Age*", "Weight*"), 
Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend that you declare your worksheet object. I turned your `LastCol` into a function.

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Function lastCol(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal row As Variant = 1) As Long
    With ws
        lastCol = .Cells(row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
End Function

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    With ws.UsedRange
        .AutoFilter Field:=lastCol(ws), Criteria1:=Array("Age*", "Weight*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With

End Sub
```

Using `ActiveSheet`, `ActiveCell`, `.Select`, `.Selection`, `.Activate`, etc is rarely good for your code. In minimal cases it's useful, but the vast majority of the time it can be a debugging nightmare.

Comment: Hey Micha, however your code looks ingenious, every time I run it a Compile Error: Expected Array message turns out pointing to the Field:=lastCol(ws) part

Comment: @SouzaSauloSaulo That's because you didn't delete `Dim LastCol As Integer` from your code. You also need to delete: `LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column`

Comment: You're right. I did as recommeded and the code works like a charm. Well done.